# how to filter out caller 0 from logback

Tags: logback

I have a custom logger(MyLogger) where I am using logback for logging data.
In the sample code below, logback logs MyLogger.logData as the calling class/method (caller {0}). I want to skip printing this and instead print only the calling class/method.
Basically just the caller{1}.

Is there a way to do so programatically ?

```
class MyLogger {

public logData(String data) {
//use logback 
logBackLogger.log(data);
}

class CallingClass {
MyLogger myLogger = new MyLogger;
myLogger.logData("test");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured solution. Implemented doLayout and called getCallerData[1] here.

public class MyLayout extends PatternLayoutBase {

```
  public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {


    sbuf.append(event.getTimeStamp());
    sbuf.append(" " );
    sbuf.append(event.getLevel());
    sbuf.append(" [");
    sbuf.append(event.getCallerData()[1]);
    sbuf.append("] ");
    sbuf.append(" ~- ");
    sbuf.append(event.getFormattedMessage());
    sbuf.append("\n");

    return sbuf.toString();
  }
```